# Syntax Error when creating prepared statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm trying to create a simple prepared statement as follows, but it through a syntax error "at or near "Insert". However, if I put the insert in a CTE, then it works no problem. Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking?

This doesn't work

```
"PREPARE stmt AS (INSERT INTO schema.table (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $2))"
```

But this does

```
"PREPARE stmt AS (WITH t1 AS (INSERT INTO schema.table (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $2)) SELECT 1)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses:

---

```
PREPARE stmt AS INSERT INTO schema.table (col1, col2) VALUES ($1, $2);
```